# Equivalent definitions of almost quaternionic structures

Tags: differential-geometry, quaternions, principal-bundles, almost-complex

I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3160823/an-almost-complex-structure-on-m-is-equivalent-to-a-reduction-of-the-structure) thread today when I was reading about almost quaternionic structures. I was wondering if there exists an argument similar to the answer to the thread above that can show that the $GL(n,\mathbb{H})\cdot \mathbb{H}^\times$-structure definitions of an almost quaternionic structure and the definition by a pair of almost complex structures $J, K : TM\to TM$ such that $J\circ K+K\circ J=0$ (in nLabs or Sommese).

I failed to find some similar condition that a subset of frames must satisfy which leads to a principal $GL(n,\mathbb{H})\cdot \mathbb{H}^\times$-subbundle of $\mathcal F(M)$. In all the text I found, this part of equivalence is either not mentioned as some authors (like Sternberg) focus on one of the definitions, or is considered as "obvious or easy" to the readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS far as I understand, the second "definition" that you give is not equivalent to the definition as a $G$-structure. (This is visible from the text in nLab, which I don't find very clear however.) The standard definition in direct terms is via a rank 3 subbundle $Q\subset L(TM,TM)$ which has the property that, locally around each point, it can be spanned by $J$, $K$, and $J\circ K$ for two anti-commuting almost complex structures $J$ and $K$. However, $J$ and $K$ themselves are *not* part of the data (and there is an $SO(3)$-freedom in their choice in each point). Indeed if you require global almost complex structures $J$ and $K$, then you get to a hypercomplex structure which corresponds to the structure group $GL(n,\mathbb H)$.

The source of the difficulty is that quaternionic scalar multiplications are not quaternionically linear maps, since the quaternions are non-commutative, and they do move the standard quaternions $i$, $j$, $k$.

For the correct definition via $Q$, there is a similar description as in the question you link to. You form the linear frame bundle of $M$ using $\mathbb H^n$ as $\mathbb R^{4n}$. Then you can either define the reduction as consiting of all linear isomorphisms $\phi:\mathbb H^n\to T_xM$ such that for each $A\in Q_x$ the map $\phi^{-1}\circ A\circ\phi\in L(\mathbb H^n,\mathbb H^n)$ is given by scalar multiplication by some imaginary quaternion. Alternatively, you take distinguished elements $J(x), K(x)\in Q_x$, use them to make $T_xM$ into a quaternionic vector space and then consider the isomorphisms $\phi$ that can be written as a quaternionic scalar multiplication followed by a quaternionically linear map.

Comment: This is such a perfectly written answer. I have seen the locally spanned bundle definition and the global almost complex structures definition, but I was sure which one of them is the correct one. I now see the note on the nonequivalence of definitions in nLabs.

I suppose you mean $A\in Q_x$ in the third line of the last paragraph?

Comment: Also, would you mind giving me some hints on the converse that a $GL(n, \mathbb{H})\cdot\mathbb{H}^\times$ structure induces such an endomorphism subbundle locally spanned by $J, K, JK$?

Comment: *... but I wasn't sure... in the first comment.

Comment: Thanks for indicating the typo, I have corrected this. For the converse, the $GL(n,\mathbb H)\cdot\mathbb H^*$ structure gives you a preferred family of linear isomorphisms $\mathbb H^n\to T_xM$ for each $x\in M$. Then you can carry over the subspace in $L(\mathbb H^n,\mathbb H^n)$ spanned by scalar multiplications by imaginary quaternions to $L(T_xM,T_xM)$ via any of the isomorphisms and verify that this always leads to the same subspace. Smoothness of the structure implies that locally you can carry over multiplication by $i$ and $j$ to $J$ and $K$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.